# use mysql in console without password but from browser with password

Tags: mysql, linux, console

how to use mysql in consloe without password for root

```
[root@toshiba01 ~]# mysql
```

but use from browser with password for root

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

how to setup mysql on linux with settings like this

Comment: You can create two different users one for console and one for phpmyadmin with same roles

Comment: i want it for root user

Answer (score 0):

You can fill root requisites in ~/.my.cnf file. So in console MySQL will not ask you for password.

~/.my.cnf:

```
[client]

user = root
password = password
host = localhost
```